# Dynamic Header In HTML with Flask/Jinja (Extend)

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I would like to make a header that is dynamic depending if a user is logged in, I have a custom login to active directory. logged in a parameter in a cookie, and I use the .get in python to fetch it.
I keep looking and not finding how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

I always get index.html no matter what, and I'm sure I have the cookie.

```
{% if logged == 1 %}
  {% extends "logged-index.html" %}
{% else %}
  {% extends "index.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I have managed it my own way, I retraced my steps and noticed I forgot to pass my variable inside my render template. Also it seems in Jinja you need "1" even though its an integer. But it does work really well this way, for those ever looking to do it. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a dynamic header/navbar or footer; couldn't you just put if/else statements into your main template that you extend from, so that different links and things show depending on whether the user is logged in or not.  This is what I did on my web app:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
  <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('account') }}">Account</a>
    </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Logout {{current_user.username}}?</a>
    </li>
  {% else %}
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('logIn') }}">Login</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('signUp') }}">Sign Up</a>
  </li>
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this depend on how often the "main" template gets loaded? If you put this in your base.html then it only gets loaded once so is_authenticated would be false and your code would never run.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I do not understand what you are after, but:

I think that it would be the same logic as this dynamic title logic:

```
 <head>
 {% if logged == 1 %}
 <title>{{ username }} - is logged in</title>
 {% else %}
 <title>Welcome to My Website!</title>
 {% endif %}
 </head>
```

I borrowed the concept from:
https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-ii-templates

Comment: I'm trying to extend my HTML pages with header/footer dynamically through the {% extend file.html %} function of Jinja. Depending if the user logged on or not.